# Why does pd.read_sas() work for individual files but not when iterating through a folder?

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I'm attempting to iterate over some SAS files and convert them to a csv. I keep getting a "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'table_name.sas7bdat' " error.

```
import os 
import pandas as pd

files = r"\\path\to\sas\tables"

for file in os.listdir(files):
    if file.endswith(".sas7bdat"):
        sasfile = pd.read_sas(file)
        df = pd.DataFrame(sasfile)
        filepath = r"\\path\to\csv\tables\{}.csv".format(sasfile)
        df.to_csv(filepath)
```

The file does exist, so I don't know what to do with this error.

I've used both my mapped letter drives and my UNC paths. I've also just run the pd.read_sas() with the individual file and that works fine.

Comment: `os.listdir` only returns the filenames. You have to `os.path.join` it with the path to containing directory.

Comment: You are trying to insert  a non-string object `sasfile` into a string.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are trying to read `table_name.sas7bdat` instead of `\\path\to\sas\tables\table_name.sas7bdat`. Change the line `sasfile = pd.read_sas(file)` for `sasfile = pd.read_sas(files+'\'+file)` to concatenate the path with the file name. That should solve your problem.